# Port Based Routing using AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

Usecase:- ON my Ec2 instances I am running 3 docker containers which are serving webpages on port 7474,5001,5002.

I created an ALB and attached my EC2 instance as TargetGroup but it shows unhealthy all the time. (that is one problem)

Second problem:- When I am adding LB Rules it's not working as expected.

my example rule is:-

under IF block:-  amundsen-nonprod.xyz.com

under Then block :- Redirect to > #{protocol}://amundsen-nonprod.xyz.com:7474/?#{query}

Similarly need to create Rule for 5001,5002.

port-based routing is possible in ALB?

OR

I need a reverse proxy between ALB and EC2 Instance where I will configure proxy pass and achieve this solution or some straight forward solution

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this under one listener. Instead you need **different listeners**.  So if you need three ports (7474, 5001 and 5002), then you need three listeners, one for each port.

Comment: Yes agree, but in my case, my first listener is not working as expected, that's the issue.